# Proper class instantiation in C# and Winforms

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

After spending the last two years as a C#/WPF/MVVM developer, I recently took over a VB/Winform project at a new company.

I've successfully converted the project to C#.  I've been doing a large amount of research, trying to figure out the best methods for this project, but I'm trying to figure out exactly how much refactoring and re-configuring to do.

My issue is this:  the previous developer created two huge static classes.  There are 30+ forms that are used for a variety of tasks.  Each form is called from an event driven by a button click on a "main menu" type of screen.  When the program initializes, a function from one of these mega-classes is called that instantiates EVERY form.  There are also an incredible number of statics and constants.

I've broken the constants out and created a specific class for them.  I'm piecing apart the mega-classes into smaller, more manageable (and responsibility specific) classes, but I've got this incredibly large initialization function that instantiates all of these forms.

Thus, my questions (finally) are these:  Is what I wrote above a resource nightmare?  Or, is this some sort of normal VB/Winform design pattern that I should keep? Should I re-write this so that each form/class is instantiated when the button calling that form is clicked, so it can disposed of when closed?

Thank you for any direction you can give me.  If I can provide more information to make this more specific, please comment and I will edit.

Comment: Thanks god this dev has been replaced.

Comment: Sounds simply like poor design to me. I can understand instantiating a couple of forms at a time, but not every form. They should only be instantiated when they are ready to be used IMO. Unless you're keeping a main form ready to be shown after a login form has completed. Even then, I still wouldn't do it that way myself. So, yes, write it your way and instantiate only as required. It's far better.

Comment: Rule of thumb is (you will hear this a lot about db connections, but it really applies to almost all classes) instantiate as late as possible, dispose as early as possible. This ensures that the GC can finalize your objects efficiently. Long lived objects drop into later rounds of GC finalization which can take a significant amount of time.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comments - I have much better direction now.  @PhiterFernandes - I'm thinking getting rid of that previous developer is just as beneficial to the company as hiring me, heh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is what I wrote above a resource nightmare?

Yes

> Or, is this some sort of normal VB/Winform design pattern that I should keep?

Absolutely not.  The design of the system is pretty much identical in VB and C#.  With some very minor exceptions the difference between the languages is just syntax.

> Should I re-write this so that each form/class is instantiated when the button calling that form is clicked, so it can disposed of when closed?

Yes in theory.  The forms should operate just as they would if you were writing in C#.  Of course if the original dev liked global state so much there could be all sorts of state lurking between one appearance of the form and the next.

There are a few features of VB that can lead weaker devs astray. The presence of the Module (essentially a static class, but sometimes more convenient) can lure some people into adding much more global state than they should.  Also in VB, it automatically creates as needed a single, global instance of each form with the same name as the class.  This can cause devs to confuse the form as a class and object - leading to the single instance of a form, rather than constructing and disposing as needed.

Comment: I appreciate your response, as well as the comments above.  It's going to be slightly insane reworking this, but at least it will result in something better than I received!